# whether to use python to the huge computing?

Tags: python, math, numerical

Sorry for my bad English.I am currently work with python and i have a problem with too slow to filling of matrix size of 10000x10000.I program a "relaxation method" where i need to test the different size of matrix.What do you think about that?...P.S I wait 3-5 min to fill one matrix 10000x10000.

```
    def CalcMatrix(self):
    for i in range(0, self._n + 1):                       #(0,10000)
        for j in range(0, self._n + 1):                   #(0,10000)
                one = sin(pi * self._x[i])                # x is the vector of size 10000
                two = sin(pi * self._y[j])                # y too
                self._f[i][j] = 2 * pi * pi * one * two   #fill
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Python loop speed is very slow.  People working with arrays and matrices in Python usually use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org).  There are other tools like cython and numba which can dramatically improve the speed in certain circumstances, but the basic idea of `numpy` is to vectorize the operations and push the hard work down to fast libraries implemented in C and fortran.

The following code takes only a few seconds on my not-very-fast notebook:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi
x = np.linspace(0,1,10**4)
y = np.linspace(2,5,10**4)
ans = 2*pi**2 * np.outer(np.sin(pi*x), np.sin(pi*y))
```

(PS: If your `_n == 10000`, then won't your matrix be 10001x10001, not 10000x10000?)

Comment: But 0..10000 has 10001 elements, not 10000.  So your `_f` will have size 10001x10001, with indices from 0 to 10000.

Comment: + I have the same iterations in another module where i need indexation.The sample::
two = w / 4 * (self._u[i - 1][j] + self._u[i][j - 1] + self._u[i + 1][j] + self._u[i][j + 1])

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements are possible.  Consider moving some of the computations out of the loop

```
def CalcMatrix(self):
for i in range(0, self._n + 1):                       #(0,10000)
    one = sin(pi * self._x[i])                # x is the vector of size 10000
    for j in range(0, self._n + 1):                   #(0,10000)
            two = sin(pi * self._y[j])                # y too
            self._f[i][j] = 2 * pi * pi * one * two   #fill
```

This value **2 * pi * pi**  can be precomputed and stored in a variable so it doesn't have to be recomputed each time in the loop.

If that is still not enough, consider using a native language like C or Fortran.

Comment: You right.I saw the memory usage in "monitor system".The process to grab about 2Gb.Type of matrix "numpy.array.float64".